# Scrape information about Visit Page and App Name on google play store

Tags: python, html

I have created the code below to scrape the app name and Visit Page Url from the google play store page.

ASOS   - Get ASOS (Line 1120)

Visit website  - Get http://www.asos.com - (q=)(Line 1121 source code)

```
url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asos.app'
r = requests.get(url)

final=[]
for line in r.iter_lines():
    if count == 1120:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        for row in soup.findAll('a'):
                u=row.find('span')
                t = u.string
                print t
    elif count == 1121:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line)
        for row in soup.findAll('a'):
                u=row.get('href')
                print u
    count = count + 1
```

*I can't seem to print the HTML here. Please open edits for that. But Please help me here!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup provides a great deal of functions that you should be taking advantage of.

For starters, your script can be cut down to the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asos.app'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'dev-link'}):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

BS4 can parse the raw HTML content and you can iterate through it via the data type.  In this scenario, you want a particular `href` link of class name `dev-link`.  Doing so, gets you the following output:

```
Found the URL: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.asos.com&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNGl4lHIgnhUR3y414Q8idAzJvASqw
Found the URL: mailto:androiddev@asos.com
Found the URL: https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.asos.com/infopages/pgeprivacy.aspx&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNH-hW1H0fYlsCjp4ERbVh29epqaXA
```

I'm sure you can tweak it a bit more to get the results you want but please refer to BS4 for more information ==> https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thanks a ton for the advice!

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Comment: is there an alternative to this because I have 6000-7000 such calls. I'll be thankful for any suggestion here!

Comment: Maybe it would help if you submit it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Store has been redesigned, now it is dynamic and the data we need stored as inline JSON.

You can still use `selenium` or `playwright` webdriwer to parse it. However, in our case, we can use the `BeautifulSoup` and [`regular expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract pretty much everything from the app page.

Firstly, extract certain `<script>` element from all  `<script>`  elements in the HTML and transform in to a `dict` with `json.loads()`:

```py
basic_app_info = json.loads(re.findall(r"<script nonce=\"\w+\" type=\"application/ld\+json\">({.*?)</script>", str(soup.select("script")[11]), re.DOTALL)[0])
```

After that we can access `dict` transformed from `json.loads()` and extract the data:

```
app_data["basic_info"]["name"] = basic_app_info.get("name")
app_data["basic_info"]["url"] = basic_app_info.get("url")
```

Don't forget to use [`user-agent` in the request](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#user-agent), then the site will assume that you're a user and display information.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "id": "com.asos.app",          # app name
    "gl": "US",                    # country of the search
    "hl": "en_GB"                  # language of the search
}

html = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

app_data = {
  "basic_info":{}
}
                     
# [11] index is a basic app information
# https://regex101.com/r/zOMOfo/1
basic_app_info = json.loads(re.findall(r"<script nonce=\"\w+\" type=\"application/ld\+json\">({.*?)</script>", str(soup.select("script")[11]), re.DOTALL)[0])
    
app_data["basic_info"]["name"] = basic_app_info.get("name")
app_data["basic_info"]["url"] = basic_app_info.get("url")
print(json.dumps(app_data, indent=2))
```

Example output

```json
[
  {
  "basic_info": {
    "name": "ASOS",
    "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/ASOS?id=com.asos.app&hl=en_GB&gl=US"
  }
}
]
```

Also you can use [Google Play Store API](https://serpapi.com/google-play-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

SerpApi code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import (parse_qsl, urlsplit)
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),         # your serpapi api key
    "engine": "google_play_product",         # parsing engine
    "store": "apps",                         # app page
    "gl": "us",                              # country of the search
    "product_id": "com.asos.app",            # low review count example to show it exits the while loop
    "all_reviews": "true"                    # shows all reviews
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)                # where data extraction happens
results = search.get_dict()
app_name = results['product_info']['authors'][0]['name']
app_url = results['product_info']['authors'][0]['link']
print(app_name, app_url, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
ASOS
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=ASOS
```

There's a [Scrape Google Play Store App in Python](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-play-store-app-in-python/#output) blog post if you need a little bit more code explanation.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.